# Maintain Form Element State on Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session, cookies

There might be some answers already to this question....or on the same lines.

I have a html form checkbox element which is unchecked by default and page load.

When clicked, I'm using Jquery to alter it's attribute to checked or unchecked so other functions run as well.

Issue is how do I maintain this state, check or unchecked when browser is refreshed. I want it to retain value previosly or last selected. Trying to avoid cookie.

Comment: Which is your server side language?

Comment: When you say, "browser is refreshed", do you mean that the page has been reloaded via the reload button (or menu option, or whatever)?

Comment: @rahul PHP is my server side language

Comment: @Pointy page has been reloaded via the reload button.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid a cookie?

Comment: @Slaks I guess I'm trying to challenge my knowledge. I know a cookie will hold state. Thinking more in the lines of a more usable solution e.g I'll imagine a form with 50 fields, how to store this if not on a session or cookie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store the value in a cookie.
[This plugin](http://code.google.com/p/cookies/wiki/Documentation#With_jQuery) will do it all automatically.

If you don't want to use a cookie, you could use HTML5 local storage.

Comment: Other than session values, cookie.... You have a form with hundreds of fields and your browser gets refreshed, usually this state is keep on session rather than cookie. Can jQuery detect a reload then grab state and pass to dom?

Comment: No.  jQuery is purely client-side and is unaware of server-side session.  You could  do this on the server.  (and autosave values using AJAX)

Comment: Accepted answer comming to conclusion the are quite some options for maintaining client side values upon refresh: cookies, session values, html5 local storage all which should be altered through ajax calls. Thanks All

Comment: @Codex: Session uses cookies too.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a cookie (fair imo) auto-save via ajax on the change is your best bet. It keeps the state of the checkbox related to that user/session/instance/db record. While the cookie just floats in the ether (has no relation to session/instance/db record/system user (only relates to browser user))

Comment: Can you expand a bit on this.

Comment: something like $(":checkbox").onchange($.ajax('checkbox/save/', $(this).val(), function(){});

Comment: Trying to make sense of it.. Your suggesting that every session keeps a record of all user selection states in a db? As far as I know there are three ways: cookie, session, db (unless using one of the new html5 markups).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an HTML 5 storage jQuery plugin for form state -> http://www.jasonsebring.com/dumbFormState